# Question about regular graph

Tags: graph-theory

Consider a regular graph $G$ of degree $k$.

Let $U \subset V(G)$. Let the number of vertices in $U$ be odd, and there are $m$ edges in $U$, that are connected with vertices in $G\setminus U$.

How can I prove that $k \equiv m \mod 2$?

Comment: $U$ is a subset of $V(G)$?  Or an element of $V(G)$?

Comment: I TeXed it as it was written. I don't really parse the post, though.

Comment: @BrianTung it's a subset

Comment: OK, edited to reflect this understanding.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Let $\ell$ be the number of edges of $G$ with both endpoints in $U$. Then argue that $$k|U|=\sum_{u\in U}\deg_G(u) =2\ell+m.$$

Comment: Thanks, i think I figure out how to proove my task!